# Invoke Methods of abstract Types

Tags: c#, reflection, abstract, invoke

I'm currently working on reflection with c# and I have a question. I try to invoke different class types which might be abstract or interface. So I just don't invoke the methods of those, because I cannot create an instance(obviously). But I'm not satisfied with this.

---

My question is: is it possible to work around this somehow and create an instance of something, where I can invoke the methods of the given abstract class type? Sorta like making a class that inherits from a Template which then can be the abstract type?

```
    foreach (MethodInfo m in _classType.GetMethods(bindingFlags))
    {
              if (_classType.IsAbstract || _classType.IsInterface)
              {
                   // only invoke instanciable types
                   MessageBox.Show("Abstract class and Interface cannot be invoked!");
              }
              else
              {
                   var ms = CreateStringFromMethodForCheckedBox(m);
                   if (s == ms)
                   {
                       m.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(_classType), null);
                   }
              }
     }
```

Comment: And what do you expect an abstract method to do where it doesn't know what to do without a definition?

Comment: You also mention interfaces, what would you expect to happen if you tried to invoke a "method" on an interface? This question really doesn't make any sense without further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically create a new class at runtime that inherits from the abstract type and then invoke the methods on your class: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/

You will have to ensure you override all the abstract methods otherwise your class will have to be abstract and you will have gained nothing.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, while the original question tries to do something that arguably shouldn't be done, this is the most reasonable workaround.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yeah, I don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: What about interfaces as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @DavidG The same technique could be used for both. ImpromptuInterface does something vaguely like this.

Comment: @john Yes, but what is the point? You would need to also implement the method, and if you're doing that, why bother creating a new class and just have the method ready to call? Quite frankly, the question is nonsense.

Comment: @DavidG For sure, I agree. But that doesn't make this an inherently bad suggestion.

Comment: @john But why add an answer to a question that makes no sense?

Comment: thanks for the answer and that probably would work for abstract classes, but another question: how about static classes? As you cant inherit from them...=P

Comment: @t0pf you don't need an instance to invoke static methods, and static classes cannot have instance methods.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis ok how to call them then? tried   Type.GetType(_classType.Name).GetMethod(m.Name).Invoke(null, null);   but that doesn't work on it :/

Comment: @t0pf it should do, unless you're passing the wrong arguments for the actual static method you're calling, or it isn't found with the default binding flags.

Comment: You already have a `MethodInfo` in the `m` variable, so that call can be simplified to `m.Invoke(null, null);`. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' is the exception. I included the BindingFlag for static, missed it somehow while copy code to website

Comment: Probably `Type.GetType(_classType.Name)` didn't work because the name doesn't include the namespace - `_classType.FullName` does.